# Add a GeoJSON to PowerBI

Tags: json, dictionary, powerbi, visualization, geojson

I want to add a GeoJSON file to create a map visualization in Power BI. I have the .geofile but I don't know how to use it in PowerPoint BI.

```
Can you help me please?
```

I mention that I don't have an Internet connection on my computer, that's why I'm trying to insert a map.

I tried already to add it as a JSON file but I Don't know the next steps.

Comment: Have a look at [Use custom maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-shape-map#use-custom-maps)